# Fortran 2008 - array variable in class

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran2008

I have a following class, where I need to store objects of type `neuron_t` and `connection_t`.

```
!> Class representing a general network
type :: net_t
    private

    character(:), allocatable                 :: net_type              !< Type of the net
    integer(kind=integer_4neuro)              :: num_of_neurons        !< Number of neurons in the net
    character(:), allocatable                 :: training_method       !< Used training method

    class(neuron_t), allocatable              :: neuron_arr(:)         !< Array containing all neurons
    integer(kind=integer_4neuro), allocatable :: input_neuron_arr(:)   !< Array of input neuron indices
    integer(kind=integer_4neuro), allocatable :: output_neuron_arr(:)  !< Array of output neuron indices
    class(connection_t), allocatable          :: connection_arr(:)     !< Array of all connections

contains
    !> Prints information about the network to the standard output.
    procedure :: print_info => print_info_impl

    !> Saves the network instance to the Fortran binary file
    procedure :: save_net_bin => save_net_bin_impl

end type net_t

interface net_t
    !> Constructor of net_t class
    !! Loads complete info about network from file
    !! @param[in] filepath Path to the file with network configuration
    !! @return Returns pointer to the new instance of the class net_t
    module procedure :: new_net_1
end interface net_t
```

I tried to initialize the array like this

```
    allocate(new_obj)

    ! Init object
    do i=1,5
        new_obj%neuron_arr(i) =  mock_neuron_t()
    end do
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
         new_obj%neuron_arr(i) =  mock_neuron_t()
        1
Error: Nonallocatable variable must not be polymorphic in intrinsic assignment at (1) - check that there is a matching specific subroutine for '=' operator
```

Do you know, what am I doing wrong? `mock_neuron_t` extends type `neuron_t`, so it should be ok.

#### EDIT:

Both `neuron_t` and `connection_t` classes are abstract, so I'm getting following error now after adding `allocate(new_obj%neuron_arr)`:

```
     allocate(new_obj%neuron_arr)
             1
Error: Allocating new_obj of ABSTRACT base type at (1) requires a type-spec or source-expr

         new_obj%neuron_arr(i) =  mock_neuron_t()
        1
Error: Nonallocatable variable must not be polymorphic in intrinsic assignment at (1) - check that there is a matching specific subroutine for '=' operator
```

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616410/intrinsic-assignment-and-polymorphism-in-fortran-2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just assign to a polymorphic variable in an intrinsic assignment (`=`). You can only do that for allocatable variables and an array element is not an allocatable variable eventhough it is a part of an allocatable array. Remember **all array elements must have the same dynamic type**.

So if you wanted to have different elements of `neuron_arr(:)` to have a different type, that is not allowed.

But you can allocate the array to some single type and use the `select type` typeguard.

```
allocate(new_obj)

allocate(new_obj%neuron_arr)  !this allocates it to the declared type neuron_t!

! Init object
select type(a => new_obj%aneuron_arr)
  type is(neuron_t)
    do i=1,5
      a(i) =  mock_neuron_t()
    end do
end select
```

But then, if you will always have one fixed type there, wouldn't `type(neuron_t)` just suffice?

Comment: Thank you very much! To be honest, I thought, that `class(neuron_t)` will set its type firmly to `neuron_t`... And I can't use `type(neuron_t)`, because `neuron_t` is an abstract class.

Comment: Then you must allocate the array in the allocate stetement to the correct type and use that type in the `select type`. But I fear your design is wrong. The array must be allocated to one common non-abstract type at once). `alocate(the_type :: the_array(size))`

Comment: I've tried that (see Edit 2 in my question), but I'm getting Segmentation fault... I have really no idea, what's wrong now...

Comment: Who knows, I think that should be a new question with a new [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I'll posts a link here, if you are interested.

Comment: I've found the mistake - mock_neuron_t constructor was returning pointer instead of an instance itself. Insert this info, please, into your answer, I think it deserves to be accepted.

Comment: I recommend to *never* use functuons that return pointers. But I don't think it belongs into this answer. It is a different problem for a new question. I'd rsther delete your **Edit 2**. How can I  even answer it when you do not show the relevant code?